# Sidebar not work after trade template $routeProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-build

Sidebar not work after trade template on $routeProvider!, After trade template i click and does not open the menu.

No error returns me only a warning with the name of my controller.

HTML

> ```
> <!-- Sidebars -->
> <div ng-include="'menu.html'"
>      ui-track-as-search-param='false'
>      class="sidebar sidebar-left"></div>
> <div class="sidebar sidebar-right"><!-- ... --></div>
>
> <div class="app" ng-swipe-right='Ui.turnOn("uiSidebarLeft")' ng-swipe-left='Ui.turnOff("uiSidebarLeft")'>
>     <div class="navbar navbar-app navbar-absolute-top">
>         <div class="btn-group pull-left">
>             <div ui-toggle="uiSidebarLeft" class="btn ">
>                 <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Menu
>             </div>
>         </div>
>        <!-- <div class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-center" yield-to="title">
>             <span>Login</span>
>         </div>-->
>
>         <!-- Top Navbar -->
>     </div>
>     <div class="navbar navbar-app navbar-absolute-bottom"><!-- Bottom Navbar --></div>
>
>     <!-- App body -->
>
>     <div class='app-body'>
>         <ng-view class="app-content"></ng-view>
>     </div>
> </div><!-- ~ .app -->
> <!-- Modals and Overlays -->
> <div ui-yield-to="modals"></div>
>
> <script src="lib/scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
> <script src="lib/scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
> <script src="lib/scripts/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
> <script src="lib/scripts/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
> <script src="lib/scripts/mobile-angular-ui.min.js"></script>
> <script src="lib/scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
> <script src="cordova.js"></script>
> <script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
> <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript">
>     var app = angular.module('appindex', [ "ngRoute", "ngTouch", "mobileangular-ui", "mobile-angular-ui.core",
> ```
>
> "mobile-angular-ui.components"
>           ]);
>
> ```
>     app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
>         $routeProvider.when('/unid', {
>             templateUrl: "unid.html",
>             controller: "unidController"
>            // controller: "unidController"
>         });
>     });
>
>     app.controller("indexController", function ($scope, $rootScope) {
>
>
>
>     });
>     app.controller('unidController', function ($scope) {
>         console.log("unidController")
>         $scope.message = 'This is Show orders screen';
>
>     });
>
>
>
> </script> </body> </html>
> ```

Other HTML

> ```
> <h2>Add New Order</h2>
>
> {{ message }}
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution : need put "reloadOnSearch: false". is right to do that way ( best practices ) ??

Thanks

> $routeProvider.when('/unid', {
>               templateUrl: "unid.html",
>               controller: "unidController",
>               reloadOnSearch: false
>           });